# Javascript: undefined Script error without any external scripts

Tags: javascript, undefined, onerror

We have a landing page for mobile customers. And we use window.onerror to catch and log JS errors in this way:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, line, col, error) {
    log(message + ', ' + error + ', ' + url + ', ' + line + ', ' + col)
}
```

As a result in our logs we see multiple undefined errors: 'Script error., null, , 0, 0'. I know that such errors may appear in case of CORS problems. When some external script doesn't have "crossorigin=anonymous" attribute. But the problem is that we don't have any external scripts at our landing page.

To double check this we even log the whole page:

```
log(document.documentElement.outerHTML)
```

Sometimes browsers insert something into our page. But mostly they don't ‍
So what else can cause such undefined error?

Maybe something from the following list?

1. SVG images such as logo
2. Google Fonts

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&amp;family=Cairo&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

3. Newest unsupported yet JS features?

**UPD 02.07.2022**

Comment: Perhaps inserted by browser extensions

Comment: Most of our customers use mobile devices. And browser extensions are not so popular in mobile. Anyway our updated log script should see any inserted external scripts. But it doesn't...